# Flash AS2 - Cursor jumps to start of text fields (input and dynamic)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm working with an old project that's written in **ActionScript 2** and recently a strange bug has appeared.

Sometimes, at any random moment, all text fields, both dynamic and input, will start acting strange. When this happens, everytime I go to highlight text or click somewhere in the field, my cursor jumps to the beginning of the text field. This just started happening recently and it happens to every single dynamic/input field, some that I haven't even edited in months.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with Flash Player or if it's something I might've accidentally changed. I've attached a gif of the issue so it makes more sense.

GIF of the problem :

[image]

Comment: if you haven't changed your code and the problem just started happening, then I would lean towards Flash player bug. Chrome updates the Flash player automatically. I'm guessing they still use [Pepper Flash](https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer) which was always (to me) like a walk in the jungle. Try using a different browser, for example IE and Safari use different Flash plugins, or try changing the version or disabling pepper flash.

Comment: Although your project is `AS2` I've added other tags in case someone watching those tags knows how to fix this issue. Does the issue appear if you make a basic test project of textfield only? I mean isolate that the problem is with _Flash Player vs any textfield_ rather than _caused by your main project code_.